# How to solve $-(AX)^{-1}+A^{-1}=X^{-1}B$ and prove $B$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

In my homework, my teacher asked a question like that:

If $A $ and $X $ are invertible matrices and $-(AX)^{-1}+A^{-1}=X^{-1}B$, prove $B$ is invertible.

I think this question is broken, because:

(1)  $-(AX)^{-1}+A^{-1}=X^{-1}B$

(2)  $-X^{-1}A^{-1}+A^{-1}=X^{-1}B$

(3)  $X(-X^{-1}A^{-1}+A^{-1})=XX^{-1}B$

(4)  $-XX^{-1}A^{-1}+XA^{-1}=XX^{-1}B$

(5)  $-A^{-1}+XA^{-1}=B$

So, question became invertible + invertible = $B$ and I can't prove that $B$ is invertible in this case. Any thoughts?

Comment: Indeed, the question is obviously false: if $X=I$, then $B=0$ is the only solution regardless of $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group of invertible matrices is not closed under addition, e.g. if $I$ is the identity matrix then $I - I = 0$: a sum of two invertibles need not yield an invertible, so that in itself is not a contradiction.

However, from your work you get $(X-I)A^{-1} = B$, and here we clearly see a problem when $X = I$.